# Adjectives that describe something is well-recognized?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an adjective (single word) to describe something that is well-recognized (that it is able to serve certain functions). It is more on the common knowledge side, not on the side of "just being popular". Some close adjective that I can think of is cherished, valued, etc., but they still sound slightly off.

Example sentence:

> Despite the "well-recognized" services he has provided to the nation, there are still ongoing disagreements on whether he should become the president.

Thank you.

Comment: The usual way of saying what I think you're looking for is 'It is highly **valued** for its ability to ...'. _Rated_, more formally _esteemed_, and in less prosaic terms _cherished_  and _prized_ are synonyms.

Comment: Please provide an example sentence. At the moment your question is unclear. (And “thank you” is used in response to an answer — it is not part of a question.)

Comment: @ David it is very common to say thank you following a question in written context. It is polite to thank in advance for people to take their time to look at the question at all.

Comment: @ychung 'able to serve certain functions' means something like 'practical' or 'usable' which is quite different from 'well known' or 'popular'. Can you give more words? Also, what did a thesaurus lead you to with 'popular' and 'valued' and 'cherished'? Please add more examples of what your intended word would work with.

Comment: The words  'highly valued', 'rated', 'esteemed', 'cherished' and 'prized' might strike you as going further in praise of 'him' than would be consistent with the thought that he would not be a good choice for president. I suggest  'acknowledged' recognises service without actually endorsing its outstanding merits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Acknowledged](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acknowledge)** is appropriate. Among other nuanced definitions,

> to recognize the rights, authority, or status of

[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acknowledge)

fits the situation you're describing.